# openMP with only one thread running?

Tags: c, openmp

I have this code in the main:

```
int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
   // Get multi-CPU/multi-GPU data
   int num_gpus;
   cudaGetDeviceCount(&num_gpus);
   printf("### Number of host CPUs:\t%d\n", omp_get_num_procs());
   printf("### Number of CUDA devices:\t%d\n", num_gpus);
   omp_set_num_threads(num_gpus);

   #pragma omp parallel
   {    
    unsigned int cpu_thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();  

    printf("### (CPU thread %d)\n",cpu_thread_id);  

    test(cpu_thread_id, num_gpus);
   }    
}
```

and the test function:

```
void test(unsigned int cpu_thread_id, int num_gpus)
{   
    printf("### Using CUDA device %d, GPU = %d\n", cpu_thread_id, num_gpus);
}
```

Even I got the output:

```
### Number of host CPUs:        8
### Number of CUDA devices:     4
### (CPU thread 0)
### Using CUDA device 0, GPU = 4
```

But I expected to have more threads like this:

```
### (CPU thread 1)
### Using CUDA device 1, GPU = 4
### (CPU thread 2)
### Using CUDA device 2, GPU = 4
### (CPU thread 3)
### Using CUDA device 3, GPU = 4
```

Why the other three threads are not running?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable the OpenMP support in the compiler?

Comment: in my makefile, I have this flag: CFLAGS        := -O3 -fopenmp -Wall -I /usr/local/cuda/include/

Comment: Depends on your compiler. GCC has -fopenmp , Microsofts cl.exe has /openmp

Comment: I suspect that the problem is because I put them in a main.cu file, I somehow need to enable it with cu file... I am finding a way to do so

Comment: OK. cu file does not work with openMP, only .c and .cpp files for GCC

Comment: Keep in mind that you must send the -fopenmp flag to both the compiler and the linker.